# bearer authorization in astream_context_create

Tags: php, header, authorization, token

I'm trying to send a request with a bearer access_token to a distant server. The access_token had been send by this server (looks like 52fhjk-24ca-4c73-1b91-12fced3b205b)

```
$header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token;
$options = array(
      'http' => array(
          'header'  => $header,
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'content' => http_build_query($postValues)
      )
  );
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

But the $result is empty

Comment: Are you sure that the request ist built properly? So, do you **expect** another response because you've verified that there should be one with the given request?

Comment: I send an other request to the same server. The one which give me the access_token. This request works and is build the same way. Except the bearer Authorization. So I suppose this is the bearer the problem

Comment: I understand what you mean. Yes the api should send me a validation message